# Is there a way to make sure inherited member is not accessible in derived classes, while still keeping the benefits of public inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have a class that holds a protected member that derived classes will inherit:

```
class Base1
{
protected:
    int baseMember_;
};

class Base2 : public Base1
{
public:
    void printBaseMember
    {
        std::cout << baseMember_ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

How can I make sure that `baseMember_` will be inaccessable in classes that derive from `Base2`?

The obvious solution would be to simply make the inheritance private:
`class Base2 : private Base1`,
but this doesn't work in my case. The reason is that private inheritance removes the is-a relationship between Base2 and Base1, which I need because I need to assign objects of type`Base1*` to type `Base2*` in several places in my code.

Is there a way to make sure that derived classes will not have access to a protected member, while still using public inheritance?

Comment: You might have private member and make the derived class `friend`.

Comment: Did you consider replacing inheritance with composition? This would solve your problem immediately.

Comment: your wording is a little confusing, because members are always inherited, no matter what is their access, only difference is wether they can be accessed or not

Comment: Can you motivate this with a real-world example? It sounds like you're trying to break substitutability (look up the Liskov Principle)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 You're right, I will change the wording. Thank you

Comment: Why not move `printBaseMember` into `Base1` and make `baseMember_` private?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The printBaseMember method is just to showcase that it's accessable, it's not actually what my code looks like. My question is just the final question in the text part of my post

Comment: @JensB Oh, I see. So, why don't you want to use private inheritance?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I explained it in my post but it's because private inheritance removes the is-a relationship and I need that for assigning derived type pointers base type pointers

Comment: @JensB What's the big difference when the result is hiding parts of the base class anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make sure that derived classes will not have access to a protected member, while still using public inheritance?

You can change the access mode of an inherited member by a `using` declaration:

```
class Base1
{
protected:
    int baseMember_;
};

class Base2 : public Base1
{
public:
    void printBaseMember()
    {
        std::cout << baseMember_ << std::endl;
    }

private:
    using Base1::baseMember_; // baseMember_ is private in the context
                              // of Base2; its derived classes cannot access it
};
```

You can also change the access mode in other ways, e.g. from `protected` to `public`. Here is an example on [godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T9ze8E).

Note, however, that the classes that derive from `Base2` can still access `Base1::baseMember_` through this name. This will bypass the access check in `Base2`. They will not be able to access it through the unqualified name of `baseMember_`. You might want to use private inheritance of `Base2` from `Base1` and `using`-declare all public members of `Base1` in `Base2` to mitigate this.

Comment: The children can still access  the member through the name `Base1::baseMember_` though. I'm not sure whether OP cares about that.

Comment: @eerorika If you are talking about children of Base1, then yes they can still access it and that's the point. That baseMember_ should be accessible in classes derived from Base1 but not in classes derived from children of Base1

Comment: @JensB The classes that derive from children of `Base1` can indeed access `Base1::baseMember_` through this name. This will bypass the access check in `Base2`. They will not be able to access it through the unqualified name of `baseMember_`.

Comment: @JensB: Thats the point. If you derive from Base2, you still can access Base1::baseMember_. So the requirement is not fulfilled for my point of view.

Comment: @Klaus Now I understand. Didn't think about that. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @JensB I've updated the answer with a possible solution. It is messy, but I can't think of anything better, unless you're willing to redesign your classes. For instance, make `baseMember_` private and implement accessors for it in `Base1`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure that baseMember_ will be inaccessable in classes that derive from Base2?

By declaring the member `private`. You can declare `Base2` to be a friend of `Base1` so that it still has access.

Comment: What do you mean? I need that variable in other classes that inherit from Base1, that's why it's there in the first place

Comment: @JensB A member exists in all instances of a class. It cannot selectively exist only in some instances. Sounds like you want a different base for those classes.

Comment: @JensB: Multiple inheritance can be helpful.

Comment: @eerorika I am aware of that, I just worded the question a bit wrong. I have edited it now so it talks about the member being inaccessible in derived classes